# How can the God Machine transport players to another place?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

This is a prelude for this question about the [spiritual effect of such transportation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46628/1015). I didn't realize there were options at the time I started implementing my story. So here's the relevant thus far, the characters were abducted, and basically put into the movie cube. They had no idea how they arrived there (same as movie) and would have been transported from wherever they were. The exit of the cube is set ~ 1000 miles away. Due to circumstances there is actually only one surviving member of the group put into the cube.

It has been determined that the surviving member disappeared from the middle of his home. Some plot that played out was that it was the middle of his room with no apparent scent trail to follow, thus "thin air". There was no sign of any struggle meaning whatever happened happened fast, and "in the middle of the room".

**My question is, how could the members have been abducted in the first place?**
 both method of subdual and transport are important to me. I presume that some infrastructure doorway was opened, by the God Machine, or an Angelic servant.

The reason for this question, is I've presumed a doorway and am wondering if it left markers in the spirit world, but apparently there's more than one possibility for a doorway, and I know nothing about that.

Comment: Can you narrow your criteria somewhat? As it is, the answer is "however you want," from a bunch of cultists drugging them and carrying them away to mystical teleportation to the Machine rewriting their cosmic location information to a new value.

Comment: Indeed, we don't handle "please fill in the blank in my plot" questions very well, which is what this seems to be. Answers can be totally arbitrary, all are equally valid, there isn't any such thing as a correct one, etc. Questions like this need to have criteria for us to meet. From the title, though, it sounded like this was asking about the mechanisms available for the God Machine to do this, rather than a request for plot, which is actually answerable and very different.

Comment: tried to add a little more, and this is sort of prerequisiting another question. Admittedly I'm trying to add detail to what I consider to be an unimportant detail of the plot. The more interesting part is going to be why. cultists don't make sense because they'd have left a scent trail, rewriting the location could work, so could a "door" of sorts opening.

Comment: Ok, this is better and much more workable.

Comment: Is there any condition you'd like the chosen method to satisfy? Like, if you're looking for something that (quoting from your other question) can be detected by demons, maybe nwod experts would have something to chew on. Your problem is that you want your players to be able to solve the enigma, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Angel Based:

An Angel could have used some means to teleported them out:

This can be done with the following Manifestation Effects (Page 225-226 of GMC):

### Means of subdual:

Angels have many abilities that a great for controlling people.
the Implant Mission Numina.
The chain of Fetter/Possess/Claim manifestations.

Taking control of them like this is one way to subdue them.

There is also the Hallucination Numina and several for manipulating emotions.

The angel could beat them up, if it materialised and carry them off,
the Innoculus numina would help it leave no scent.
And it could use numia from demon (see below) to clean up the scene.
Though this is the most likely to fail

## Means of transport:

- Avernian Gateway: Opens a Underworld Gate, this gateway can be passed through by anyone to get the the Underworld. Fades after 1 scene.
- Shadow Gateway: (Rank 3+ angel only), this opens a gateway into the Shadow, again passable by anyone -- *even by accident* (So could be used as a trap to trick them in). Fades after a scene.

Once they have been transported to the Shadow, or Underworld they could be right into some serious infrastructure on the other side -- or the angel could use other means of the other control (discussed above) to take them futher.

The Shadow is a particularly good choice since it would leave traces for a werewolf party to see, as you have mentioned in your other question.

They could have been tricked into the Shadow Gateway, or manipulated using some of the abilities in described above.

## Output/Occult Matrix Based

God machine infrastructure produces output -- as change upon the world.
Some examples of how this could have been used:

- *Rewrite where a door leads* (for a scene). Instead of this elevator openning on the the ground floor it opens into a dark place full of cogs. You don't notice until you have stepped forward and the elevator door is closed <sub>(I wouldn't do that to PCs but to NPCs sure)</sub>
- *Rewrite the cosmic data that says someone's position*: He is not there, he is here. This is kinda boring and unfun. But if you want to get the message across that the god machine is all powerful and we are ants beneath its thumb then its actually pretty good.
- *Open a worm hole*: Spacetime is a sheet, bend it just right so that two places are touch and then just a little hole and you are sucked right through.
- *Convert a person to a digital representation* that can be carried out by an Angel and reconstituted later. (Inspired by the Data Form Demon ability from DtD)

The list of infrastructure outputs that can solve this problem is limited only by your creativity.

> "...many things most other supernatural beings regard as impossible can
> be achieved with the right occult matrix." DTD, p63

You could also give any of these abilities to an angel in the form of a special piece of equipment (there are many examples in the books, such as the typewriter that creates evidence (DtD, p70))

### More options can be found in Demon

I have just to focused on options from the God Machine Rules Update.
There are great pills of Embeds and Demonic form abilities in Demon the Decent,
all of those are valid abilities for an Angel to possess as Numina. (some example angels in DtD do).
Some exploits are also valid inspiration, such as Behind the Curtain, that lets a Angel Teleport between infrastructure.

One particular kind of Embed that might be good as a numina for this, is the embeds the rewrite the Evidence. This could be used to hide a abduction by cultists. Or mindcontrol to have them walk straight out.

Comment: might I ask where you derived the list of output/occult matrix from? Trying to find some of these things in my copy (note: also have a copy of DtD as well now)

Comment: xebiterracide: I made them up, because a with the right occult matrix the output can be what ever is needed. This is one of the God-like aspects of the god machine. I can't find my original reference but i fond one in demon